# I'm Trying to Change My Background, But it Doesn't Work. What's Wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create some javascript that will change the body's background-color every second. I researched it and came up with this code, but it didn't work.

```
var x;

    function changecolors() {
        x = 1;
        setTimeout(change, 1000);
    }

    function change() {
        if (x === 1) {
            color = "blue";
            x = 2;
        } 

        if (x === 2) {
            color = "green";
            x = 3;
        }

        if (x === 3) {
            color = "red";
            x = 1;
        }

        document.body.style.background = color;
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with this code?

Comment: There are a couple of problems here, you haven't called the `changeColors()` function. Also you probably want to use `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout` as that will only run once.

Answer (score 1):

**setTimeout() :** To execute a function only once, after a specified number of milliseconds.

**setInterval()** method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

> Resource : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

**Note :** You Change `x` to 1 , 2 and 3 , I think you want change background color blue,green,red after 1000ms :

So Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` :

**Full Code:**

```js
var x=1;

setInterval (change,1000);

function change() {

   if (x === 1) {

      color = "blue";

      x = 2;

   } 

   else if (x === 2) {

      color = "green";

       x = 3;

   }

   else if (x === 3) {

     color = "red";

     x = 1;

   }

   document.body.style.background = color;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here what I can see is you have decleared the function but have you called the function `changecolors();` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, your 2nd and 3rd `if`s should be made into `else if`s; otherwise, you'll always get `red`. This is because you hit the 1st if since `x === 1`, then immediately hit the 2nd if (since now `x === 2`) and finally, hit the last if (since now `x === 3`) and by the end of every function call, you will have `color === 'red'` and `x === 1`.

Beside that, if you want it to cycle *every* second, you either have to re-call `setTimeout(change, 1000);` at the end of your function because setTimeout only fires once per call; Or, you can use `setInterval(change, 1000);` instead, which will run every second on its own.

Consider something like this instead, which will cycle through an array of colors, by incrementing (and then resetting back to 0, using the `%` operator) your variable and accessing an array, rather than using ifs.

```js
var x;

var colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red'];

function changecolors() {
  x = 0;
  setInterval(change, 1000);
}

function change() {
  document.body.style.background = colors[(x++) % colors.length];
}
    
changecolors();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at my commented solution:

```js
var lightnumber = 0; // this variable saves the current state of the background lights
var lights = [
    "#ff0000", "#ffff00", "#00ff00"
]; // this variable saves all possible lights. You can also use "red", "green", "yellow" or whatever is acceptable for CSS.

setBgColour = function() {
    // at first we decide which colour shall be next, so we increase
    // the lightnumber by one, except, if we are already at green, then we start over at 0
    lightnumber = lightnumber == (lights.length - 1) ? 0 : lightnumber + 1;
    // and here we set the light according to our lightnumber variable
   document.body.style.background = lights[lightnumber];
   // and lastly, call the function again after a second
   setTimeout(setBgColour, 1000);
}
```

```html
<h1>Traffic Light</h1>

</br>
<button id="next" onClick="setBgColour()" type="button">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've errors in your code. Check that example from [W3CSchools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see – set Timeout is **NOT** like `delay(3000)` (from other language) or something like that. You can learn a bit trying (it wouldn't work) to make it pausing, not deploying with delay. You will see then it's not pausing whole script, but only running that what's inside with delay. Check it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("It will be first? Not!"); }, 6000);
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("It will be second? Not!"); }, 2000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

And now solution.

```js
var timeout = 1000; //time of delay (in ms)
var backgroundColors = ["blue", "green", "red"]; //table with colors for background

var fingerOnColorsArr = 0; //var that'll store actual position, just like your's x var

var action = function() //definition of function that'll change background color
{
  document.body.style.background = backgroundColors[fingerOnColorsArr];
  
  fingerOnColorsArr++; //just go forward
  
  //if we're out of array's reach – go back to begin
  if (fingerOnColorsArr == backgroundColors.length)
  {
    fingerOnColorsArr = 0;
  }
};

//execute function `action` in infinite loop with interval `timeout`:
setInterval(action, timeout);
```

You can modify first two lines and simply change interval or colors pattern. By the way – it's possible to make it shorter, but as I can see – you're newbie, so more important is understanding everything what's code doing.